# Can I share an event as an ICS file?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

How can I share a single Google Calendar event with other users who may not necessarily use Google Calendar?

I do not want to share it via email address, but want to provide something like an ICS file or a link.

I want it to be compatible with most other calendar applications, such as Apple Calendar, MS Outlook, etc.

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way to do this (without creating another calendar) is to create the event and then invite yourself. You'll receive an email from Google with the .ics file as an attachment.

Comment: You are also able to send an email to yourname+69@gmail.com, plus addressing is supported by most companies. Inviting yourself from your own google calendar doesn't trigger sending an invite email to me if I'm the only one in the event.

Comment: I just tried adding myself as a guest, and it doesn't even trigger an email to myself even though I am not the only guest.

Comment: This does not seem to work any more. The message does not seem to have an .ics file as an attachment as of May 2023.

Comment: @DimaChubarov It works for me when using a + alias as of the end of August 2023.

Comment: @Rubén, thank you for pointing this out. Yes, it does work with a + alias as Ray Foss suggested.

Answer (score 18):

There isn't a nice and direct way to do that.

However, you could do the following:

1. Create a new temporary calendar from the `+` sign in the calendars list.
2. Go to your event and copy/duplicate it to the temporary calendar.
3. Export the calendar to an ics file.
4. Delete the event from the temporary calendar.
5. Repeat 2-4 when necessary.

Comment: Works, but can I add something to get a response from all attendees ?

Comment: I believe there's a way, but haven't tried it. Look for ics fields related to organizer/rsvp etc. Maybe you can set it manually in the file

Comment: Hm .. it seems this only works if you know who attends upfront https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rsvp.html

Comment: @lony Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions.

Answer (score 6):

On a Samsung Android phone at least, open up the event on your phone in the Samsung Calendar app, share as ICS file, email it to yourself, others, etc.

Comment: The question is about sharing a Google Calendar event. Please elaborate on what what will be the steps to send the Google Calendar event to the Samsung Calendar app.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find any option in Google Calendar to export a single event, but there is a workaround.
Simply invite yourself with a non-Gmail account, by default the event will be attached to that invitation.
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

For people looking to create a simple event that you can share easily look below. I tested importing this event into Google Calendar and Apple Calendar.

Create a ".ics" file in your favourite text editor and use the following template below.

**NOTE** that the dates are in UTC.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//YourCompany//YourApp//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1234567890
DTSTAMP:20230901T090000Z
DTSTART:20230905T120000Z
DTEND:20230905T130000Z
SUMMARY:Meeting with John Doe
LOCATION:123 Main St, Anytown
DESCRIPTION:Discussing the new project
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

A breakdown of the key components:

- BEGIN:VCALENDAR and END:VCALENDAR: These mark the beginning and end of the iCalendar object.
- VERSION:2.0: Specifies the version of the iCalendar format used.
- PRODID: Identifier for the product that created the iCalendar object.
- BEGIN:VEVENT and END:VEVENT: These mark the beginning and end of an event.
- UID: A unique identifier for the event. Create a UUID with a tool such as https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4.
- DTSTAMP: The time the event was created in UTC.
- DTSTART: The start time of the event in UTC.
- DTEND: The end time of the event in UTC.
- SUMMARY: A brief description or title for the event.
- LOCATION: The location of the event.
- DESCRIPTION: A more detailed description of the event.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

1. Create a new Google Calendar. I named mine Export_ICS
2. Go to the calendar that has the event you wish to have in ICS format.
3. Click on the Event.
4. In the top right corner, left click on the "hamburger" menu (the 3 stacked dots)
5. Select "Copy to" and the newly created calendar, the one I named Export_ICS.
6. On the left side of the screen and hover over the calendar you created.
7. Left-click on the hamburger menu and select "Settings and sharing."
8. Scroll down slightly and select "Export Calendar." That downloads the calendar as a ZIP file.
9. Extract/Open the ZIP file.
10. You should now have an ICS file of the event you wanted to be exported.

##### IMPORTANT

Go back to the newly created Calendar, Export_ICS, and delete your event. If you fail to delete this event, the next time you use this process, you will end up with an ICS file containing *two events*, your previously created event, and the new one.

FYI, I ran the resulting ICS file through https://icalendar.org/validator.html and only received WARNINGS regarding line length, no ERRORS.

Answer (score -1):

As far as known, you cannot export a single event from Google Calendar. You can only export calendars as a whole. Instead, as someone mentioned, you can add yourself to the guest list of the event with another email, and use the ICS file that gets sent to you.

Comment: Already mentioned in previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

While Google Calendar sharing does not work for me as one would like it, and sending mails to yourself is more like a workaround, using an **online creator tool** like those in the following links makes it easy.

You enter your information for the event in a form and export an iCal file, which then can be attached to your email. Looking great in all mail services as far as I could test it.

https://www.terminsysteme.de/ics/

https://jennamolby.com/ics-link-generator/

or from **[github](https://github.com/Wysie/icalgen)**:

http://icalgen.yc.sg/

or from **[github](https://github.com/alihuber/icalendar_creator)**

http://icalendar-creator.herokuapp.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/150098)

Comment: @serenesat if you would look at the links, there is no information presented on these sites. So there is nothing to present here as information and no need to copy paste this comment. The sites simply are web-apps that export ready ical files that you can attach to your mail and are readable for all calendar systems, as i wrote.

Comment: You should add the explanation of how to use the web apps to the answer.

Comment: @Rubén I thought “online creator tool that exports an ical file and attach to your email” is enough explanation for such a simple task.